# please wait .... for first docker based jenkins boot

Tags: docker, jenkins, centos

I have installed dokcer based jenkins/blueocean like jenkins official documentation. 
but  Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work ...  took a lot of time (more than one hour). I have sufficient hardware resource
I changed useSecurity variable in config.xml but result didn't changed.

How can I solve this problem

**EDITED:**

docker logs -f ***:

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:32 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @687ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:32 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:32 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:32 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-02-15T16:53:49.381Z; git: eb70b240169fcf1abbd86af36482d1c49826fa0b; jvm 1.8.0_212-b04
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@2ca26d77{Jenkins v2.176.2,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@dc9876b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @2038ms
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:33 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:35 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:36 AM jenkins.bouncycastle.api.SecurityProviderInitializer addSecurityProvider
INFO: Initializing Bouncy Castle security provider.
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:36 AM jenkins.bouncycastle.api.SecurityProviderInitializer addSecurityProvider
INFO: Bouncy Castle security provider initialized.
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:44 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM hudson.util.Retrier start
INFO: Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@39458357: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Aug 05 07:27:46 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@39458357]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@182e99cc
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:46 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@182e99cc: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:47 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7476ccfb: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Aug 05 07:27:47 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:47 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@7476ccfb]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3098fdf5
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3098fdf5: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 05, 2019 7:27:47 AM jenkins.install.SetupWizard init
INFO: 

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

1**************************6

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Aug 05, 2019 7:27:51 AM org.kohsuke.stapler.LocaleDrivenResourceProvider getLocaleDrivenResourceProviders
INFO: Registered LocaleDrivenResourceProvider: jenkins.MetaLocaleDrivenResourceProvider@6e683bfd
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Have you checked the logs of the container? Find its name by inspecting the output of `docker ps` and then go in with `docker logs -f [name]`. Also, please show us the command that you used to start the container and your Dockerfile (if you wrote one).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the club )) Have you read this thread? [[JENKINS-51716] Blueocean stuck in loading - Jenkins JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51716?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)

Comment: @bellackn thanks. I edited post and add logs to its

Comment: @Yasen thank you. I read it but I cant solve the bug

Comment: Thanks, can you please also show the command that you used to run the container?

Comment: @bellackn `docker run   -u root   --rm   -d   -p 8080:8080   -p 50000:50000   -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   jenkinsci/blueocean`

Comment: This works without problems on my machine. Where exactly are you facing the error?

Comment: I cannot access this page, this is a private IP address. Maybe add a screenshot to your question? Also, you could try to flush your browser's cache.

Comment: @bellackn . screen like "https://www.google.com/search?q=please+wait+while+jenkins+is+restarting&client=ubuntu&hs=yT6&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA94Kuu-zjAhVEDewKHVkUAXkQ_AUIESgB&biw=1535&bih=802#imgrc=JZ7NeijsyYsIgM:"

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your browser? Try to visit the address in a private window. I don't see anything  wrong in your configuration or in your logs... Some last ideas: Is the host that Jenkins runs on behind a firewall or CDN? Does the browser console show anything when you visit the site?

Comment: @bellackn I dont know why, but when i open console, browser automatically went to next step. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there was something wrong with your browser(cache), refreshing/opening the dev console solves the problem, nothing wrong concerning Docker or Jenkins.